# What is the recommended approach to use Mule choice router with XSLT

Tags: xslt, mule

I am using the below shown snippet of `choice` element in my Mule 3.3 flow. `XSL Transformer` feeds the choice element. XSL Transformer is supposed to return a `String` (name of an entity) and on the basis of string value, I use choice router to push it to different jms queues.

```
<flow name="ProcessOrder">
    .
    .  
    <xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsl/getEntity.xslt" returnClass="java.lang.String"/>
    <choice>
        <when expression="payload.contains('ABC')">             
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="order.queue1" />
        </when>
        <when>
        </when>
        <otherwise>         
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

XSL Transformer returns this payload
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>ABC`

My question is how do I compare the `String` returned. I don't think `payload.contains()` is the best way to do this, though it solves my purpose and also we won't have matching entities returned which are ever like `ABCxy` but still this is not a full proof solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the omit-xml-declaration part in your xslt as shown below. This will give you the raw string without the prolog.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    >

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
...
...
```

This will give

```
"ABC" as output instead of     "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>ABC"
```

Then in the expression use it like

```
<when expression="#[message.payload.contains('ABC')]">
```

This way it should work.

Comment: @Learner. Please let me know if the solution is working for you.

Comment: Your pointer for `omit-xml-declaration` attribute helped me to get rid of prolog. Thank you for your answer. Though I ended up using `#[message.payload == 'ABC']` instead of `#[message.payload.contains('ABC')]` as that's a more accurate evaluation. `contains` is more of a `substring` function.

Comment: Good that you got your solution. I gave it as contains because i thought you were looking for substring function in the conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<when evaluator="xpath" expression="/result/" ...
```

Obviously, your XSLT will need to retur a well-formed XML document with the desired result in an XML element that is neatly accessible by XPath.

Comment: I **have** to use `XSL Transformer`. `XPath` doesn't offer the programming capability that I need here. Thanks for looking though

Comment: oh I see what you're saying. You mean edit XSLT to return XML instead of String and then use XPath. Isn't this an overkill?

Comment: Not really.  The output of XSLT is usually XML, and by using XPath, you will be getting the exact element you want, from the right structure.  If you need to expand this further, it will be readily expandable.  However, I am not sure whether the return type will remain String or would be another type - would need to try it out.

Comment: From Mule In Action 2ed, The XSL transformer is extremely versatile as far as source and return types are concerned. This transformer also infers the best matching return type based on the input type (or the returnClass attribute if it has been set).

Answer (score 0):

On Mule website they suggest to use `expression-splitter-router` evaluator this is an example from mule website of how to use it:

FruitBowl containing an apple, an orange, and two bananas. When Mule receives this object, we want to route the fruit to different locations: the AppleService, BananaService, and OrangeService.

```
<service name="Distributor">
    <inbound>
       <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="distributor.queue"/>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <!-- FruitBowl.getFruit() List -->
        <expression-splitter-router evaluator="bean" expression="fruit">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="apple.service.queue">
                <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.tck.testmodels.fruit.Apple"/>
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="banana.service.queue">
                <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.tck.testmodels.fruit.Banana"/>
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="orange.service.queue">
                <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.tck.testmodels.fruit.Orange"/>
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>
        </expression-splitter-router>
    </outbound>
</service>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is a good example but will not work in my case as returned object from XSLT will always be String and my intention is not to split the payload but push it to a specific queue based on payload content.

Comment: FYI In Mule 3, `service`s are deprecated in favor of `flow`s.

Comment: I agree with you David but the example I took out from mule 3.3 user guide here http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Expressions. They should update their documentations :)